# How to handle an event clicking in the hyperlink in RichTextBox

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0

How can handle an event clicking in the hyperlink in RichTextBox element in Windows Phone. Here is my code of RichTextBox element:

```
        <RichTextBox>
           <Paragraph>
Download it directly to the <Hyperlink Foreground="Blue" TargetName="_blank" NavigateUri="http://itunes.apple.com/fi/app/goalapp/id502461189?ls=1&amp;mt=8">iTunes Store</Hyperlink> or <Hyperlink Foreground="Blue" TargetName="_blank" NavigateUri="https://market.android.com/details?id=com.strikersoft.meramal.se">Android Market</Hyperlink>. The application is launched for Swedish app store.
     </Paragraph>
    </RichTextBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

RichTextBox Control has LinkClicked event. It handles all of the url clicks within its text.

Comment: I know, but I need to add some additional logic to this event

Answer (score 0):

Hyperlink has "Click" event. Just handle it:

```
<Hyperlink Click="eventHandler" />
```

Comment: thanks, but when I tried to fill Xaml property of RichTextBox there was an error, so this event will not work if I add Click event as attribute

Comment: What kind of error? Could you show error message? Maybe you missing to add a handler eventHandler to *.cs file? =)

I tried it now and it works.